# How to get SQL script output in java?

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, jpa, pojo

I'm using Spring JPA repository and aiming to select the SQL generate statement. 
In Oracle SQL developer I can run this query as script -

```
select /*insert*/ *  from table_name
```

and it will return the insert statement. Spring JPA seems to be treating this as just the select statement. I have an @Data class but I'm not sure if I need to annotate a String with @Column because I can't give the response a label so if I put a column annotation it would always be wrong.

Any suggestions for this?

Thanks in advance :)

This is the Repository class

```
public interface InsertRepository extends JpaRepository<Insert, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT /*insert*/ * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITION", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Insert> getInsert();
}
```

And the Insert object:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Insert {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String insert;
}
```

Comment: This is a native query, so run it as a native query.

Comment: I'm running it with nativeQuery = true, edited to show the objects

Comment: Can you give an example of what Oracle returns? It seems a little strange to me that you want to map this to an entity, it sounds to me like the query will just return a string.

Comment: Oracle is returning the insert statements. Maybe it doesn't need an entity mapping, I just want to read the SQL console in java, the issue is that scripts don't return a result set, they print to the SQL console

Comment: Yeah that is highly Oracle specific, I don't think that's possible using standard JDBC which also means it is out of scope for anything built on top of JDBC. If it is at all possible to get programmatic access to the information you are after, it likely involves writing a stored procedure.